# How to create an java based application which will take input from website

Tags: java, json

I want to create an application java based for desktop which can fetch data from site.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far

Comment: You mean like using an API of a website (like google APIs) or scraping data off an actual website?

Comment: scrappinfg datta of actual website

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial to look at how to fetch data from URL's in java.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html